# Add value 1 in an multidimension array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimension numpy array in python created like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.zeros((3,5))

>>> print a

>>>[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]`
```

I want to add 1 with ++1 at a[1:2] to a[2:3]. The result should look like this:

```
>>>[[ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

How can I reach this? Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot,

krank42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer depends heavily on the question why?

You can `flatten`, make your changes on one row, and `reshape`:

```
af = a.flatten()
af[2:9] += 1
a = af.reshape(a.shape)
```

In this case, you will have to calculate the indices yourself. In this case it is simple: [0,2] turns into row x #columns + column = 0 x 5 + 2 = 2 and [1,4] into 1 x 5 + 4 = 9. Please note that the indexing in python starts from 0, not from 1. The first column of the first row is [0,0].

There are some auxiliary functions for the index mathematics, in this case the closest is `numpy.ravel_multi_index`, but it may be a bit too complicated for the 2D case.